# Linq query multiple master tables

Tags: linq

I have a question related to LINQ queries in SharePoint 2010.
I have few master lists -
1> Team (ID, Name)
2> Lifecycle (ID, Name)
3> Technology (ID, Name)
4> Users (ID, Name)

Then there is a mapping table having ID's of all the above & some data
example "Knowledge Table" (Team ID, Lifecycle ID, Technology ID, User ID, Knowledge title)

Now i want to develop a custom webpart that will display all the data in Knowledge table, But i want to see the names of Team ID, Lifecycle ID, Technology ID, User ID